# NoSuchElement Exception Error

Tags: java

I seem to be having some trouble getting my code to run properly here. What this is supposed to do is it is supposed to read from a text file and find the name, quantity, and price of an item on each line then format the results. The tricky bit here is that the items have names that consist of two words, so these strings have to be differentiated from the quantity integer and price double. While I was able to get this working, the problem that I am having is with a singe space that is at the very end of the text file, right after the last item's price. This is giving me a `java.util.NoSuchElement Exception: null`, and I cannot seem to move past it. Can someone help me to work out a solution? The error is on `thename = thename + " " + in.next();`

```
while (in.hasNextLine())
        {
            String thename = "";

            while (!in.hasNextInt())
            {
                thename = thename + " " + in.next();
                thename = thename.trim(); 
            }
            name = thename;
            quantity = in.nextInt();
            price = in.nextDouble();

        }
```

Comment: You need to check if there are more tokens before calling next().

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the `Name quantity price` string is properly formatted.  There might not be enough tokens in the string.  To check that there are enough tokens for the name:

```
 while (!in.hasNextInt())
        {
            thename = thename + " ";
            if (!in.hasNext())
                throw new SomeKindOfError();
            thename += in.next();
            thename = thename.trim(); 
        }
```

You don't have to throw an error, but you should have some kind of code to handle this issue properly according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the logic of your inner `while` loop:

```
while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
    thename = thename + " " + in.next();
}
```

In English, this says "while there's *not* an int available, read the next token". The test does nothing to help check if the next action will succeed.

You aren't checking if there is a next token there to read.

Consider changing your test to one that makes the action safe:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    thename = thename + " " + in.next();
    thename = thename.trim(); 
    name = thename;
    quantity = in.nextInt();
    price = in.nextDouble();
}
```